# How to load huge dataset for conversion into spacy JSON in colab?

Tags: dataset, google-colaboratory, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

I have a dataset having 65 million entries in IOB format.
So, while converting it to spacy Binary format using the command:

***!python -m spacy convert /content/train.tsv /content/ -s -c ner***

The colab would show the:
***tcmalloc: large alloc .....
^C***

Could you please give me some way of circumventing this issue. I don't have a lot of experience with colab or profound knowledge of data science concepts. Any reference would also work.

Is it possible to take each file and then make its binary and merge anything like this exists?

Thank you!